# How to passthrough SecurityToken with HttpClient in Asp.net Web Api

Tags: httpclient, saml, adfs, claims

We have two ASP.NET Web API applications (Application1 is where users login and use the AngularUI, Apllication2 is a Shared WebAPI2 backend without UI) that make use of (SAML?) Claims to Authorize users via a IIS WSFederationAuthenticationModule (Ex. STS for localdev and ADFS for production).

We would like to use a HttpClient to passthrough the claims or the SecurityToken from Application1 to 
Application2.

How can we pass the authorized claims?
Via Cookies?
Via Headers?
Via a SAML SecurityToken?